# How can I upload files to an S3 bucket with dots in its name using the PHP SDK?

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload files to my bucket using a piece of code like this:

```php
$s3 = new AmazonS3();
$bucket = 'host.domain.ext'; // My bucket name matches my host's CNAME

// Open a file resource
$file_resource = fopen('picture.jpg', 'r');

// Upload the file
$response = $s3->create_object($bucket, 'picture.jpg', array(
    'fileUpload' => $file_resource,
    'acl' => AmazonS3::ACL_PUBLIC,
    'headers' => array(
        'Cache-Control'    => 'public, max-age=86400',
    ),
));
```

But I get the "NoSuchBucket" error, the weird thing is that when I query my S3 account to retrieve the list of buckets, I get the exact same name I'm using for uploading **host.domain.ext**.

I tried creating a different bucket with no dots in the name and it works perfectly... yes, my problem is my bucket name, but I need to keep the FQDN convention in order to map it as a static file server on the Internet. Does anyone know if is there any escaping I can do to my bucket name before sending it to the API to prevent the dot crash? I've already tried regular expressions and got the same result.

Comment: Try `host.domain.ext.s3.amazonaws.com`?

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not work either. It seems that the PHP SDK does not like dots. I tried creating a different bucket name without dots and the code works perfectly, but as I said, I need the FQDN to map it as a public server on the Internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd try using path style urls as suggested in the comments in a related [AWS forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=69108) thread...

```
$s3 = new AmazonS3();
$s3->path_style = true;
```

Comment: Thanks Anthony, that solved the problem. Additionally, I had to specify the region, as my bucket is not in the US: `$s3->set_region(AmazonS3::REGION_EU_W1);`

Comment: S3's SSL certificate is tied to *.s3.amazonaws.com, which causes PHP/cURL to complain when accessing buckets using DNS-style addressing. More recent versions of the official PHP SDK switch to path-style URLs automatically when necessary.

Comment: This is not an answer to the original question, just a workaround.